# Kibana and Elasticsearch error

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I want to access to Kibana by http://IP:80. 
Nevertheless when I visit the pageI obtain these errors:

> Upgrade Required Your version of Elasticsearch is too old. Kibana
>   requires Elasticsearch 0.90.9 or above.

and

> Error Could not reach http://localhost:80/_nodes. If you are using a
>   proxy, ensure it is configured correctly

I have been looking up these problems on the internet and I have included these lines without success...

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: http://localhost:80
```

My Elasticsearch version is in fact 0.90.9.

What could I do?
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my scenario Logstash using node protocol by default. if you apply command :

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true'
```

if you are getting `"number_of_nodes" : 2,` means logstash using node protocol and becoming part of cluster .so kibana taking it other node that was in older version of elasticsearch.
solution :
put  `protocol => transport` in logstash config file for shipping to ES.
like,

```
input {  } 
    output {
      elasticsearch {
        action => ... # string (optional), default: "index"
        embedded_http_port => ... # string (optional), default: "9200-9300"
        index => ... # string (optional), default: "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        node_name => ... # string (optional)
        port => ... # string (optional)
        protocol => ... # string, one of ["node", "transport", "http"] 
    }
```

if you want to access on port 80 than you have to do  proxy . otherwise kibana listen on 5601 by default. if you still facing same issue then use latest version of logstash + kibana +elasticsearch .

Answer (score 0):

Download advanced version of elasticsearch as the version you are using is not compatible with Kibana. Try using latest elasticsearch version.